# Uploading images as Data URI using IE/Safari

Tags: jquery, filereader, data-uri

Currently I have a drag-n-drop solution using jQuery and `FileReader`, which works with Chrome and Firefox. I use `readAsDataURL` to get a Data URI of the image to be uploaded, and then POST the data to PHP to be written as a file on the server.

I've heavily condensed my code, but the process looks like this:

```
this.bind('drop', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    var files = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

I then have a separate function that invokes `$.ajax` to POST the Data URI. 
I also have a check for browsers that can support `FileReader`:

```
$.fn.initUpload = function() {
    return (window.FileReader) ? this.initDnD() : this.addClass('disabled');
}
```

where `initDnD()` has the previous example.

For the `.disabled` class, I'm falling back on an `<input type="file" />` for Safari/IE. Is there any way I can take the file that a user selects and immediately convert it to a Data URI on Safari/IE? I only ask this because I would rather reuse my PHP script that saves Data URIs as images.

Comment: A Quick look through the MDN says that safari and IE8 support this. While I can't chop up some code for you real fast, they've created [a Standalone Example](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data) that should guide you through the steps necessary for this to work.

Comment: The standalone example doesn't link to a walkthrough of anything? It shows that you can POST a file to something and retrieve a data URI, but that would require a page transition; is there some way to do this asynchronously?

Comment: Well of course, by using AJAX.

Comment: The problem is that I can't send a POST for files, and I need to convert them to Data URIs first. The above example seems like you have to upload the files to the server, and then receive a Data URI. I'm trying to bypass that typical upload process because I'm trying to upload these files asynchronously.